# Evaluate an infinite convergent sum

Tags: integration, summation, infinity

Evaluate $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ln (2n) - \frac{\ln (2n + 1) + \ln (2n - 1)}{2}$

I have no idea how I should approach this problem.

So far, I've only studied partial sums and Riemann integrals, but I don't really understand how and when apply these concepts.

It seems like I can't calculate this, using partial sums, since there is no explicit formula for $S_n$.

Comment: It just a telescoping sum

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt are you sure? without the telescoping property $\log(..)$ type sums are notoriously difficult to evalueate

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt ... I realised & could not workout how to delete my comment ... it is the Wallis product for pi by 2.

Comment: @David Splutterwit good observation! here is a corresponding link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic result due to Wallis is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n} {2n-1} \frac{2n} {2n+1} =\frac{\pi} {2}
\end{eqnarray*}
So your sum is $\frac{1}{2} \ln (\frac{\pi} {2})$.

Answer (score 4):

That is clearly related with Wallis' product, but if we lack such knowledge, we may simply exploit the integral representation for the logarithm provided by Frullani's integral:
$$ \forall a,b>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}\,dx = \log\frac{b}{a}\tag{1}$$
allowing us to write the given series (that is absolutely convergent, since its general term behaves like $\frac{1}{n^2}$) as:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(2n+1)x}+e^{-(2n-1)x}-2e^{-2nx}}{x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^x}\cdot\frac{dx}{x} \tag{2}$$
The problem now boils down to showing that
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tanh x}{x}e^{-2x}\,dx = \log\frac{\pi}{2} \tag{3}$$
that is an instance of the more general
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tanh x}{x}e^{-mx}\,dx = \log\,\left(\frac{4\,\Gamma\left(\frac{m+4}{4}\right)^2}{m\,\Gamma\left(\frac{m+2}{4}\right)^2}\right).\tag{4}$$